# Programming Kinect using Java on Win 7 64

Tags: java, kinect

I have Kinect for xbox. I have installed Kinect SDK.

I am trying to program Kinect using Java in Eclispe IDE. I have tried several tutorials.    I have installed:

1. openni-win64-1.5.4.0-dev.msi
2. nite-win64-1.5.2.21-dev.msi
3. SensorKinect092-Bin64-v5.1.2.1.msi
4. sensor-win64-5.1.2.1-redist.msi

and it didn't work, when I run NiSimpleRead it open and then close immediately.

also I have tried to install all above but win32 and it also didn't work.

I have installed ZigFuOpenNI.exe and the problem still exists.

I have tried the tutorial installation of J4K library using the instructions in this site: 
http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/j4k/eclipse.php

and also it is not working it seems that there is problem with jogl and gluegen-rt native libraries because when I open the folders in the Package Explorer they are empty, but I am following the instructions correctly.

In my case, Kinect only works with Processing 2.2.1. I have tried the examples in this program using SimpleOpenNI and it works.

My question is how can I connect Kinect to Java in Eclipse.

I would be very much appreciated for helping me.

Comment: Have you tried [`jnect`](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jnect/)?  Interesting question.  Unfortunately it out of scope for SO.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I tried using https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jnect/wiki/RightHandTrackerTutorial and the problem when I run the program and press Start Game button it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe the JOGL and GlueGen JARs are missing. Please can you give more information about that problem? Do you have an error message? a stack trace?